# Can the Cancel button be removed from a UIImagePickerController in OS 3.2?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

The problem:

*There was an image here, but the link went dead. It shows a `UIImagePickerController` shown inside a popover, as a view inside of another controller (that is, it's not the root VC of the popover). It sports a Cancel button.*

Can this button be killed in a popover? I can remove the button in the `ABPeoplePicker*Controller` that appears when picking Contacts by editing the private VC's navigation item on the fly, but this one eludes me (no `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods are called by the `UIIPC`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change it to something else (not sure about removing) because `UIImagePickerController` inherits `UINavigationController`. Then you can get

```
UINavigationBar *bar = picker.navigationBar;
[bar setHidden:NO];
bar.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
```