# Remove Cancel Button in UIImagePickerControler--iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an App where it displays a UIImagePickerController on launch. The controller displays the cancel button, but there is nothing to cancel to. Is there any way to remove the button?

NOTE: This is *not* a duplicate of [Can the Cancel button be removed from a UIImagePickerController in OS 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980156/can-the-cancel-button-be-removed-from-a-uiimagepickercontroller-in-os-3-2). The answer there for iOS 3.2 does not work for me in iOS 5.

Comment: I used it in two apps 4 and 5.  But I did not see any cancel button.  Are you doing anything unusual way to present it?

Comment: I am presenting the UIImagePickerControler in my viewDidAppear, which means as soon as the dialog is dismissed, through the cancel button, it reappears. Most of the code I presented it with was copied from the Apple docs, so I don't think that that is it. I am on the simulator, if that changes anything (although I am not using the camera type--I am using the saved pictures library).

Comment: If the view is intended to be a root view, why are you using another view controller to present it?

Comment: Because after it is disposed of I have to switch to another view. I know that that would be easier, but I need to know how to get rid of the cancel button. The fact that the user can hit cancel and not have anything happen would be dumb on any platform, let alone iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to put UIImagePickerController not modally, but in original way (as we do it with ordinary custom UIViewController). So, I need no the cancel button in the UINavigationBar.

There are no documented ways to remove the cancel button. But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7047729/1113343) I found some idea.
I just added this code in my AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    for (UINavigationItem *item in navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
        if ([[item title] compare:@"Cancel"] == 0) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)item;
            [button setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

So the cancel button is hidden now. But if you pick some folder in you photo albums the next view will be with that button (and it is not hidden).
Then I tried to add code like this:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    for (UINavigationItem *item in navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
        if ([[item title] compare:@"Cancel"] == 0) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)item;
            [button setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

I get the cancel button is hidden in all navigation stack inside UIImagePickerController's navigation.

But while the new view is appearing (animation transition) the cancel button is appearing too.

I don't know how to fix this problem.

---

However I think that it is a tricky and inefficient approach. Because it can break your application in the future iOS updates. So you can use the answer to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685160/uiimagepickercontroller-subview-alternative) question. But it is different approach at all.

P.S. Sorry for my language.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like exactly what I needed. I'll reply once I have tried it.

Comment: By the way, @Yuriy Muzyukin, I don't want to present the image picker with animation. I need exactly what you say at the beginning. Thanks for the long answer!

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 7 and 8 the above solution will not work,

There is small change that should be done because we cannot use navigation item from navigation bar. The following will work like a charm

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
   didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil;
}
```