# UIImagePickerController Subview Alternative

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

I am looking to integrate the ability to select images from the built in library into an iOS app.

UIImagePickerController seems like the obvious choice.
However, it only works as a modal view controller. For design reasons, the image selection in this app needs to be part of an UIViewController itself.

After some research on the web and searching the StackOverflow archives, it seems I will need to implement my own Image Picker from scratch using `ALAssetsLibrary`to access the images stored on the device. However this is quite a task (if done well).

Thus my questions are:

1) Is there already an existing library or class (or would someone be willing to share his/her existing code) for this purpose?

2) Alternatively, is there a way to extend the UIImagePickerController to add more interface elements to it?

Comment: UIImagePickerController works just fine in iOS 5+ if you add it's view as a subview of another view and add it as a child view controller of a parent view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some of my own projects, I use the [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController), but this again is meant for modal presentation.

But since it's open source, you may be able to make modifications to allow it to be embedded in the way you want it to be presented.