# Removing cancel button in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an app for ios 5.
I need to remove the cancel button on UIImagePickerController i searched for this problem on the forum but didnt get exact answer can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I'm trying to imagine a case where this wouldn't be a horrible user experience. Can you describe the use case where the user would want to be prevented from canceling the operation?

Comment: Perhaps where it's not modal?

Answer (score 2):

That is because it is not possible to remove that cancel button. That is an inbuilt function and you can not make changes in the same.

Comment: Hi Sarah thanks for replying so is there any way that i can disable it or can i do something else in its function - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController*)picker

Comment: Check this. I have not used it so not sure about it,but may be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980156/can-the-cancel-button-be-removed-from-a-uiimagepickercontroller-in-os-3-2

Comment: @Sarah Please stay with the original answer. Do not fiddle with the internals of `UIImagePickerController`, it can, and will, break your app in future iOS updates.

Comment: @PeyloW : yes I know that. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Swift Version, compatible 4+

To remove the navigation bar :

```
imagePicker.view.subviews
            .filter { $0.isKind(of: UINavigationBar) }
            .forEach { $0.isHidden = true }
```

for removing the buttons only :

```
imagePicker.view.subviews
            .filter { $0.isKind(of: UIButton) }
            .forEach { $0.isHidden = true }
```

Voilà

Answer (score 1):

I will give the best method to achieve this:

- First create a subclass of the UiImagePickerController
- in the subclass respond to the `UINavigationBarDelegate` method 
  `- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar 
  shouldPushItem:(UINavigationItem *)item`

you dont have to do anything like setting the delegate or adding a protocol, just override the method inside your custom UIImagePcikerController.

- in this method return `NO` for the cancel item (which is the first one)

Answer (score 0):

I did this with [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to remove only the cancel button.  UIImagePickerController exposes a property called showCameraControls, which will hide the bottom bar with the cancel button and the camera button, as well as the controls for flash, HDR, and flip camera, giving you just the camera preview.

If you want to provide an experience without a cancel button, you'll have to create a camera overlay view of what you want.

Assuming you have code invoking UIImagePickerController, you can turn off camera controls like this:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setShowsCameraControls:NO];
```

Assuming you'll overlay it with your own view without the cancel button, you'll add this (assuming you have a UIView called cameraOverlay:

```
[imagePicker setCameraOverlayView:cameraOverlay];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will hide Navigationbar itself along with the `Cancel` and `Title`

```
    let videoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    for view in videoPicker.view.subviews {
        if let navBar = view as? UINavigationBar {
            navBar.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

If you want to remove the cancel button alone, dig deep into `navBar`

Answer (score -1):

When you present the UIImagePickerView try puting the below code

```
for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"subviews=%@",subview);
    NSString *className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [subview class]];
}
```

By the above code you can get the navigation controller used for displaying the cancel button.. Once you get the navigationController Set its leftside button to nil..

I have not used it but hope it can be of help to you