# Remove/hide cancel button on 'UIImagePickerController UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary' iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode5

Is possible remove or hide the 'cancel' button on a 'UIImagePickerController UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary'?

Comment: Please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708219/removing-cancel-button-in-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: This answer will not work with ios 7